# How to Assign Different Colors to Category Buttons on a Wordpress Blogroll

Tags: css, wordpress, button, colors, categories

How do I assign different colors to individual category buttons that automatically display under a blog post title on the blogroll? Something like the different button colors seen on this [blogroll](https://melbournecriminallawyersblog.com/).

I see that on the blog above, each category has a different identification:

- category 1: .pgafu-post-categories a:nth-child(4n+1)
- category 2: .pgafu-post-categories a:nth-child(4n+2)
- category 3: .pgafu-post-categories a:nth-child(4n+3)
- ...and so on...

Any new category is assigned a different div and it would be easy to CSS control the color of each identification.

But with the theme we're using, there is only one identification for all category buttons:

- category 1: .element_4 a
- category 2: .element_4 a
- category 3: .element_4 a
- ... and so on...

Hence whatever color is assigned to that identification via CSS, the color is automatically applied to all category buttons. There is no differentiation.

How do I make each category acquire a different div/identification? Thanks in advance.

Our new blog is still under construction but you can view it [here](https://www.staging4.criminal-lawyers.com.au/blog).

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to provide a specific solution since you have not provided your actual html, but you can use the `nth-of-type()` pseudo-selector which allows styling of different instances of the same element

Also note that the nth-child pseudoselector refers to an element that is a given child of something - so if your elements are all children of a given parent div or other element - tyou shoukdstill be able to target them using a regular nth-child() pseudoselector.

```css
button{
 color: white
}

button:nth-of-type(1) {
 background: red
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
 background: blue
}

button:nth-of-type(3) {
 background: green
}

button:nth-of-type(4) {
 background: black
}
```

```html
<button class="element_4a" type="button"> Button 1</button>
<button class="element_4a" type="button"> Button 2</button>
<button class="element_4a" type="button"> Button 3</button>
<button class="element_4a" type="button"> Button 4</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I updated my post to include a link to our current blog (still under construction) for the HTML, etc. I feel like I need to edit our theme files to make the goal possible but I'm not sure how or which file.